# Double integral over the hypocycloid

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

A 3-cusped hypocycloid has the form

[image]

and defined by he parametric equations:
$$
x =  2 \cos \phi - \cos(2 \phi),\\
y =  2 \sin \phi + \sin(2 \phi),\\
\phi \in [0,2\pi].
$$

**Question:** Suppose I want to find a double integral over the area enclosed by the curve. Is there a change of variables that transforms the 3-cusped hypocycloid  bounded area  into a more convenient area, for example, into a square?

Comment: Please rephrase. The hypocycloid is a *curve*; you want to talk about the double integral over the planar region it bounds. Why not use variables $(t,\phi)\in [0,1]\times [0,2\pi]$ to generate that region? Can you see what I'm suggesting you do for the mapping?

Comment: what is $t$ here?

Comment: Can't you guess? You want to fill in the parametric curve parametrized by $\phi$, say, by joining the points to the origin at the center. Perhaps polar coordinates would be a hint (although $\phi$ is not the polar angle $\theta$, of course).

Comment: you are implying that $t=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=...$?

Comment: So we have to compute the area of the region $D$ enclosed by the given curve? This means to compute $$A:=\iint_D 1\cdot dx\;dy\ ,$$the integral of the constant function $1$ over $D$. Or we have to consider "**a**" general double integral over $D$. If the above $A$ should be computed, are we constrained to "have a square" in between in the computations?! (In other words, the OP "*for instance*" has an imperative meaning.)

Answer (score 5):

I will type $t$ instead of $\phi$ at all places.
The point $O(0,0)$ is an interior point. For each point $P(t)=(2\cos t-\cos 2t\ ,\ 2\sin t+\sin(2t))$ consider the segment from $O$ to $P(t)$ as being parametrized as $u\cdot P(t)$. We thus obtain a map $f$ from $[0,2\pi]\times [0,1]$ to the domain $D$ enclosed by the given curve,
$$
(t,u)\to f(t,u):= u (2\cos t-\cos 2t\ ,\ 2\sin t+\sin(2t)) = (x,y)
\ .
$$
Then we have formally:
$$
\begin{aligned}
dx &= (2\cos t-\cos 2t)\; du + u(-2\sin t+2\sin 2t)\; dt\ ,\\
dy &= (2\sin t+\sin 2t)\; du + u( 2\cos t+2\cos 2t)\; dt\ ,\\
dx\wedge dy 
&= (2\cos t-\cos 2t)\cdot 2u( \cos t+\cos 2t) \;du\wedge dt\\
&\qquad + 2u(-\sin t+\sin 2t)\cdot (2\sin t+\sin 2t)\; dt\wedge du
\\
&= (2\cos t-\cos 2t)\cdot 2u( \cos t+\cos 2t) \;du\wedge dt\\
&\qquad - 2u(-\sin t+\sin 2t)\cdot (2\sin t+\sin 2t)\; du\wedge dt
\\
&=\Big((2\cos ^2 t+2\sin^2 t) +(\cos t\cos 2t-\sin t\sin 2t)
\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad
-(\cos^2 2t +\sin^2 2t)\Big)\; 2u\;du\wedge dt
\\
&=(1+\cos 3t)\; 2u\;du\wedge dt\ .
\\[3mm]
&\qquad\text{ So the area of the domain $D$ is:}
\\[3mm]
\operatorname{Area}(D)
&=
\iint_Ddx\; dy
\\
&=
\iint_{(t, u)\in[0,2\pi]\times[0,1]}(1+\cos 3t)\; 2u\; du\; dt
\\
&=
\left(\int_0^1 2u\; du\right)
\left(\int_0^{2\pi} (1+\cos 3t)\; dt\right)
\\
&=1\cdot 2\pi=2\pi\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Is the result in the range we expect? Here is the geogebra picture of the situation:

[image: mse 4798596]

We expect an area of $D$ which is between

- the green area of the equilateral triangle with circumradius $r=2$ obtained by building the tangents to the curve in the points $P(0)$, $P(2\pi/3)$ and $P(4\pi/3)$,
- and of the brown one with the circumradius $R=3$ obtained by connecting the points $P(\pi/3)$, $P(\pi)$, and $P(5\pi/3)$.

The areas of the two equilateral triangles stay in proportion $(3:2)^2=9/4$, a number bigger two. Geogebra gives the values $5.2$ and $11.69$ - so which area should be closer? Well, optically it is the smaller area that approximates closer. And indeed, the obtained area $2\pi\approx 6.2831853\dots$ is between $\frac 32r^2\sin 120^\circ=3\sqrt 3\approx 5.1961524\dots$ and
$\frac 32R^2\sin 120^\circ=\frac {27}4\sqrt 3\approx 11.69134\dots$

Answer (score 4):

By Green's theorem, you have
$$ \frac12\int_\gamma(-ydx+xdy)=\iint_Ddxdy $$
and hence
\begin{eqnarray}
\iint_Ddxdy&=&\frac12\int_\gamma(-ydx+xdy)\\
&=&\frac12\int_0^{2\pi}\bigg[-(2 \sin \phi + \sin(2 \phi)d(2 \cos \phi - \cos(2 \phi))\\
&&+(2 \cos \phi - \cos(2 \phi))d(2 \sin \phi + \sin(2 \phi)\bigg]\\
&=&\frac12\int_0^{2\pi}\bigg[-(2 \sin \phi + \sin(2 \phi)(-2 \sin \phi + 2\sin(2 \phi))\\
&&+(2 \cos \phi - \cos(2 \phi))(2 \cos \phi + 2\cos(2 \phi))\bigg]d\phi\\
&=&\int_0^{2\pi}(1+\cos(3\phi))d\phi=2\pi.
\end{eqnarray}